# (R) How to remove all rows that have a NULL value in a specified column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to remove every row that has a value of `NULL` for the `lyrics` column from my data frame `tsLyrics`. I have tried

```
tsLyrics <- filter(tsLyrics, lyrics == NULL)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = lyrics == NULL`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 338 or 1, not size 0.
```

I have also tried changing my syntax to:

```
tsLyrics <- filter(tsLyrics, is.null(lyrics))
```

However, when I do this I get an empty data frame. How should I approach removing these `NULL`s?

In case it is applicable, each entry in the `lyrics` column is either a list or a `NULL`

[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxoyS.png)

```
structure(list(track_name = c("Run (feat. Ed Sheeran) (Taylor’s Version) (From The Vault)", 
"The Very First Night (Taylor's Version) (From The Vault)", "All Too Well (10 Minute Version) (Taylor's Version) (From The Vault)", 
"State Of Grace (Taylor's Version)", "Red (Taylor's Version)"
), lyrics = list(structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), NULL)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Share an example of the data you want to filter

Comment: @IceCreamToucan added a screenshot, not sure how to actually attach a file or do it in a better way

Comment: If you type `dput(head(tsLyrics))`, you will get code which you can paste here which will recreate the first few rows of your data

Comment: @IceCreamToucan sorry if I am doing this wrong - I added it, but it does not look very clean at all.

Comment: You did it right, but it looks to me like there are no NULLs in the first 6 rows, so maybe that's a bad example. Instead of `head(tsLyrics)` can you subset to a part that has NULLs? Or, by NULL did you mean what's in `lyrics` for those first 6 rows, which is actually a 0-column tibble?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Sorry, not NULLs in the first 6 rows - I have added a range which should be all filled, but the last one is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to map over the column with the `is.null` function

```r
df <- structure(list(track_name = c("Run (feat. Ed Sheeran) (Taylor’s Version) (From The Vault)", 
"The Very First Night (Taylor's Version) (From The Vault)", "All Too Well (10 Minute Version) (Taylor's Version) (From The Vault)", 
"State Of Grace (Taylor's Version)", "Red (Taylor's Version)"
), lyrics = list(structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), NULL)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   track_name                                                           lyrics  
#>   <chr>                                                                <list>  
#> 1 Run (feat. Ed Sheeran) (Taylor’s Version) (From The Vault)           <tibble>
#> 2 The Very First Night (Taylor's Version) (From The Vault)             <tibble>
#> 3 All Too Well (10 Minute Version) (Taylor's Version) (From The Vault) <tibble>
#> 4 State Of Grace (Taylor's Version)                                    <tibble>
#> 5 Red (Taylor's Version)                                               <NULL>
df %>% 
  filter(!sapply(lyrics, is.null))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   track_name                                                           lyrics  
#>   <chr>                                                                <list>  
#> 1 Run (feat. Ed Sheeran) (Taylor’s Version) (From The Vault)           <tibble>
#> 2 The Very First Night (Taylor's Version) (From The Vault)             <tibble>
#> 3 All Too Well (10 Minute Version) (Taylor's Version) (From The Vault) <tibble>
#> 4 State Of Grace (Taylor's Version)                                    <tibble>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>